# @Model not supported in Razor Views for VB?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Is not the `@Model MyModelClass` notation not supported in VB Razor Views?  It's not working for me.  What is the construct for it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The equivalent construct to `@model` statement in C# Razor in VB is `@ModelType`.

Comment: Thanks for that - nowhere on the ASP.NET tutorials or syntax guides did I find this. SO wins again